# How to hook Flare-built online help into a web application?

Tags: flare, madcap

I have uploaded some MadCap Flare online help files into my SVN repository. What code does the web developer use to get these help pages into the online help of the web application?

Answer (score 0):

On their website, MadCap Software provides a context sensitive help guide for Flare. It should show you what the technical writer and what the developer has to do to link the help system to the application, depending on which type of help output you are creating. You can find it here: http://docs.madcapsoftware.com/flare2018/FlareCSHGuide.pdf.

Fair warning, so far I have no experience with the information provided in the guide, as our CHM help system was already up and running when I started working on our Flare project, so I've never initially linked a Flare project to an application, just updated an existing project (therefore the "**should** show you").

If you have further questions about Flare, the peer-to-peer support forum (https://forums.madcapsoftware.com) is usually a really good resource. There are a couple of very active users there that really know the ins and outs of Flare. Might be worth it to go over there for Flare specific information, as Flare is a niche tool probably only known to few here on stackoverflow, but it's the bread and butter for the guys and gals over in the MadCap forums.

Answer (score 0):

I use Electron to wrap a custom browser window around my Flare output... works like a charm! I've also created a React component that puts my Flare output into the component. Therefore, any React application could use the 'help component' I created.

If you want to see an example, let me know.

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your answer to include an example. That will make it easier for readers in the future to understand your solution, and apply it to similar problems. Thank you.